# can't connect to remote mysql server using java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I connect by lan 2 computer. fisrt pc is server and installed wamp server. And i using that server from client pc by browser. But my java program connect to server. and no any error.
Help me. 
Here is my code snipped:

```
public class dataconnection {

public Connection getDBConnection() throws Exception {
    Connection conn = null;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

    String sURL = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.102:8081/db_name?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
    String sUserName = "root";
    String sPwd = "pass";
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(sURL, sUserName, sPwd);
    return conn;
}
}
```

Here is:**app.class**

```
try {
            dataconnection datacon = new dataconnection();
            String customername = jTextField1.getText();
            String organization = jTextField2.getText();
            String serialkey = jTextField3.getText();
            GetMacAddress();
            String sql = "Select data from cols where id='" + id + "'";
            Connection con = datacon.getDBConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if (!rs.next()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Invalid",
                        "Error",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
```

else
{
 bla bla...
}

Comment: Is db_name a placeholder or is that in the actual connection string?

Comment: Can you post here the exception you are getting?

Comment: debug not working from this line Connection con = datacon.getDBConnection(); and no any error

Comment: Sorry. My java program is can not connect to server.

Comment: If you don't have any error, it's probably that you're catching it and ignoring it. Remove your catch block, or at least make sure you call exception.printStackTrace() inside it.